# How to dismiss two UIViewControllers in iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios8, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am working on iPhone application using Objective C. As I need to dismiss two UIViewControllers at once, so I am using below code :

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code is working fine in iOS6 and iOS7, but it is not working in iOS8. I have checked by using breakpoint, my ViewController viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear method is calling but my view is not loading at all, so as an output, I am getting blank white screen. Can anyone please help me that for iOS8, how can I solve this problem, should I need to use presentedViewController instead of presentingViewController?

Comment: If there are multiple vc presenting, I would add a notification observer to the VC you want to dismiss and send a notification to ask it go away.

Comment: Thanks @Horst for the response. but as per my requirement, need to dismiss two ViewControllers.

Comment: then add observer to both VCs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Swift code**

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
    var tmpController :UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController;

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {()->Void in
        println("done");
         tmpController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
    });
}
```

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3jiodnp1zttdda/demoHomeKit.zip?dl=0)

---

**Objective-c code**

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *trmpVC = self.presentingViewController;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [trmpVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq3qss2cjv618bu/demoCanDelete%202.zip?dl=0)

Comment: @JageenThansk for your answer, i am using objective c don't know much for shift. Please provide me the solution in objective C, if possible.

Comment: @AnandGautam edited and will upload sample project also.

Comment: @AnandGautam did work in your environment also ?, If not please check with sample project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66918/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-jageen).

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
NSArray *arrVC = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[arrVC objectAtIndex:arrVC.count-2] animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What exactly does it do? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes sure.. your code is crashing due to index issue. Actually it should be NSInteger currentIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
        if( currentIndex-2 >= 0 ) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex-2] animated:YES];
        }

Comment: no no.. actually i have tried with the above, but it's not even dismissing at all.

Comment: I think you should go with delegation approach, where popping a view controller send message to delegate to again pop a view controller.