# Dismiss Popover after touch

Tags: swift, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I've created a popover inside my `MainViewController` when some button its touched using the `UIPopoverPresentationController` and set like it's delegate like it's showed in the WWDC 2014, in the following way :

> **MainViewController.swift**

```
class MainViewController : UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

   @IBAction func showPopover(sender: AnyObject) {

      var popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopOverViewController") as UIViewController

      popoverContent.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
      var popover = popoverContent.popoverPresentationController

      popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 419)
      popover!.delegate = self
      popover!.sourceView = self.view
      popover!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(180,85,0,0)

      self.presentViewController(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil)        
   }  
}
```

The popover have a View inside  it and when the View it's clicked with a Tap Gesture Recognizer I show  `LastViewController` using a modal segue, the modal segue is created through the Interface Builder, not in code using an action to present the another `LastViewController`

Once the `LastViewController` is dismissed and I'm back in the `MainViewController` the popover remains open.

Inside the **PopOverController** I only have the default code nothing more.

> **LastViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func dismissVIew(sender: AnyObject) {        
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

The above code is used to dismiss the `LastViewController` once the button inside is touched.

> **Storyboard**

[image]

How can I dismiss the popover once the another `LastViewController` it's visible, or before the another `LastViewController` should be opened?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show me the code you had written for function which called when user tap on popover.

Comment: @Jageen I've not created an action to show the modal , I did it using the Interface Builder

Comment: @Jageen I going to update my question with all the code I used

Comment: I have already answer of same problem over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481756/how-to-dismiss-two-uiviewcontrollers-in-ios-8/27483252#27483252

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**I have already answer same problem over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481756/how-to-dismiss-two-uiviewcontrollers-in-ios-8/27483252#27483252)**.
There scenario  is different but solution is same

You have to write code for dismiss presented view controller on completion of current view controller. 
Write below code on your dismissVIew method of `LastViewController.swift`

```
 var tmpController :UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController;

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {()->Void in
            println("done");
            tmpController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
        });
```

Download [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KnvB_2930aZmNBLUZITWlQQ0k/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 6):

In your button action on the FinalViewController, have you tried:

```
@IBAction func dismissMe() {
//this should tell the popover to tell the main view controller to dismiss it.
    self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I've reproduced the issue you reported, and this definitely worked for dismissing both the final and the popover.

Answer (score 1):

here is how I would do it.

I usually use lazy initialization for the PopoverViewController and it's ContentViewController

```
lazy var popoverVC: UIPopoverController = {
    let vc = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: self.contentVC)

    vc.delegate = self

    return vc
}()


lazy var contentVC: UIViewController = {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as UIViewController

    vc.modalInPopover = true

    return vc
}()
```

inside my contentViewController I hold a reference to the UIPopoverController.

```
var popoverVC: UIPopoverController!
```

then when I show the popover i just assign the popoverController to the contentViewController

```
@IBAction func showPopover(sender: UIButton) {
    contentVC.popoverVC = self.popoverVC

    let viewCenterRect = self.view.convertRect(self.view.bounds, toView: self.view)

    popoverVC.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(viewCenterRect), CGRectGetMidY(viewCenterRect), 1, 1), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros, animated: true)
}
```

finally I dismiss the Popover programmatically inside an `@IBAction`

```
@IBAction func dismissPopover(sender: AnyObject) {
    popoverVC.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the viewcontroller you can override viewWillAppear()

Inside of this block dimiss it

```
 override public  func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        _viewToDismiss.removeFromSuperView()
    }
```

But the above code assumes you have a reference to the PopOver object, which I don't think is good practice based on how you described the problem.

Rather, why not have the viewcontroller that created the PopOver be responsible for destroying it. Put this in the class that listens for the button touch (which I also assumes creates the PopOver as well)

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   _popOver.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but nothing happens in both cases in the ViewController opened from the popover and in the PopOverController with viewWillDisappear and nothing.

Comment: Post some code, I can't tell anything from your description

Comment: I put the code inside the MainVIewController where the PopOver it's called to show , I thought the other PopOverViewController and the other VIewController called when the VIew it tapped inside the PopOver it's not relevant, because what I want it's destroy the PopOver created once the another VIewController it's visible

Comment: Can you post what you did when you tried my method and it didn't work?

Comment: There is a .dimissPopOver() you can call on the popOverController. Have you tried calling that?

Comment: I don't have a `.dimissPopOver()` because I use the  `popoverPresentationController ` not the class UIPopOverController to show it, see the delegate in the MainViewController

Answer (score 0):

> The popover have a View inside it and when the View it's clicked with a Tap Gesture Recognizer I show another ViewController using a modal segue.

As far as I understand from what you say, you should be able to call [`dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) from the action associated to your tap gesture recogniser. This will dismiss the popover you presented calling:

```
self.presentViewController(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can call this method on the popover view controller itself, depending on what is more convenient for you:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.

Comment: See updated question in relation with the action you mention to the Tap Gesture

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jageen answer

## Swift 4.2

```
let tmpController :UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController;

self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {()->Void in
    print("done");
    tmpController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil);
});
```