# popover close from another view controller swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

i work with Xcode 8 and swift 3.
i have a viewcontroller (Class User:NSViewcontroller) with a button.
This Button has an action:

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {

  let popover = NSPopover()
  popover.contentViewController = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Popover") as! NSViewController

  popover.show(relativeTo: button.bunds ,  of: button, preferredEdge: .maxX)
}
```

This button open another view controller as popover.
this popover view controller (Class Popover:NSViewController) do some actions.

now my question is: how can I close the popover viewcontroller from the popover class?

Comment: You can probably refer to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224059/dismiss-popover-after-touch

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the above code but in order to create your PopoverView and dismiss it. Here are the steps:-

1) Create one new View Controller names as PopOverViewController.swift

2) Implement the below method inside that:-

```
func updatePopOverViewController(_ button: UIButton?, with delegate: AnyObject?) {

    guard let button = button else { return }

    modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.up]

    popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor

    popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button

    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = button.bounds

    popoverPresentationController?.delegate = OtherViewControllerClass
}
```

3) Inside your OtherViewControllerClass implement the following code:-

```
extension OtherViewControllerClass: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}


func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    //your code for eg. if you want to change the tint color of our button
}

 //When you tap on button it will show the popover and while tapping on yourViewcontroller view it will dismiss the popover accordingly.
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let viewController = PopOverViewController()

    viewController.updatePopOverViewController(sender, with: self)

   present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answers. but  nothing works - perhaps, i do it wrong. i attached my demo project. can somebody shows me how it can be realize ? 

https://www.file-upload.net/download-12475831/PopOver.zip.html

Answer (score 0):

Well I might be totally guessing here as I have no idea about how your *ViewController* is written but this should fairly work

```
self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The basic thing here is you can access the VC which presented the popover and then call dismiss over it.