# Dismiss the xib view in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created two xib files for my login condition. When first I click a button it presents the first xib file in that file there is another button on which when I click it to present another xib file upon the first one. Here I run my API and on success, I'm trying to dismiss the second xib file but it isn't dismissing the second xib. I have marked the breakpoint also and when I run it comes to the breakpoint but it isn't dismissing again. This is how I present my first xib file,

```
let signingAlert = SigningAlert()
signingAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(signingAlert,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

and here I calling my second xib,

```
@IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let loginAlert = LoginVC()
    loginAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    present(loginAlert,animated: true,completion: nil)
    // self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
}
```

and on my API success condition, I write this code for dismissing the xib's,

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That's what I'm writing an API. ` func loginAPICall(){

```
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    shadowView.isHidden = false

    let param1 =  "username="+userNameTxt.text!
    let param2 =  param1+"&password="+passwordTxt.text!
    let param  =  param2+"&grant_type=password"

    print(param)
    LoginService.instance.LogInUSer(body: param) { (success) in
        if success{

            let status = LoginService.instance.status

            if status == 500{
                print("500")
                self.showAlert(message: "Error!.Server not found")
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.shadowView.isHidden = true
            }
            else if status == 404{
                print("404")
                self.showAlert(message: "Error!. Data not found try again")
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.shadowView.isHidden = true
            }
            else if status == 400{
                 self.showAlert(message: "Error!. Username or password is incorrect.")
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.shadowView.isHidden = true
            }
            else if status == 401{
                print("401")
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.shadowView.isHidden = true
            }
            else if status == 200{
                self.showsuccessAlert(message: "You are successfully LoggedIn")
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.shadowView.isHidden = true

                let userName = LoginService.instance.loginModelInstance[0].userName
                let accessToken = LoginService.instance.loginModelInstance[0].accessToken
                let userId = LoginService.instance.loginModelInstance[0].userID
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue("true", forKey: "status")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(userName, forKey:"name")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(userId, forKey:"userId")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey:"accessToken")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
            else{
                self.showAlert(message: "Error!. Try again")
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.shadowView.isHidden = true
            }
        }else{
            let status = LoginService.instance.status
            print(status)
             self.showAlert(message: "Error!. Try again")
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.shadowView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}`
```

but it is not dismissing my xib's, how can I dismiss that?

Comment: past `API`  success code.

Comment: i have edited check that. @PratikPrajapati

Comment: Do you want to dismiss both the xibs @Awais

Comment: yes i have to dismiss both at once. @Mansi

Comment: can you show your showsuccessAlert code @Awais

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224059/dismiss-popover-after-touch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Login VC

```
protocol LoginDelegate: class {
   func didDismiss()
} 

class LoginVC: UIViewController {
  weak var delegate: LoginDelegate?
  var successAlert: UIAlertController?
```

Replace

```
if status == 200{
   self.showsuccessAlert(message: "You are successfully LoggedIn")
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with

```
if status == 200 {
  self.onsuccess(message: "You are successfully LoggedIn")
```

Add the following function `onsuccess` in your Login VC

```
func onsuccess(title: String = "Success!", message: String) {
  successAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert) 
  successAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { [weak self] _ -> Void in
       self?.delegate?.didDismiss()
       self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }))
   present(successAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

In your signing VC

```
@IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let loginAlert = LoginVC()
        // Add delegate to self
        loginAlert.delegate = self
        loginAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        present(loginAlert,animated: true,completion: nil)
        // self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
 }
```

and add

```
extension SigningVC: LoginDelegate {
  func didDismiss() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: i didn't get this line  successAlert = UIalertController..... what is this for? @Mansi

Comment: this is my success alert code  func showsuccessAlert(title: String = "Success!", message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: Share your code for `self.showsuccessAlert(message: "You are successfully LoggedIn")`, I can explain then

Comment: Check the updated answer, if you don't understand let me know @Awais

Comment: i have this func in an extension and when i'm trying to write ur code there i'm getting some errors for  successAlert. @Mansi

Comment: What errors? in extension of your view controller? and did you add the `var successAlert: UIAlertController?` in your view controller? @Awais

Comment: @Awais You are presenting signing class, on that you are having Login class, and on that you are having your success alert, so you need to follow above steps for step by step dismissal of all 3!

Comment: let me explain u, i have successalert func in an extension which is in seperate class i'm just printing my message in body successalert is not in loginVC class. another error is that as u said above 
// Remove `let` keyword here
    loginAlert = LoginVC()
bY removing let i got error use of undefine identifer. @Mansi

Comment: Then you need to have your alert's action handled in loginVC class, because alert is also presented so it needs to be dismissed. So add your alert from loginVC class

Comment: this is the hierarchy of my classes HomeClass -> present SigningAlert class -> present LoginVC class . @Mansi

Comment: Okay And where are you calling API from? @Awais, loginVC right?

Comment: what about the let should i remove that? if so than what to do with error? @Mansi

Comment: yup i'm calling API in loginvc and in success case i have to dismiss all xib and go to homeVC. @Mansi

Comment: let me check. @Mansi

Comment: In ur func where there is written UIAlertController its showing error this
extension SigningVC: LoginDelegate {
  func didDismiss() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}. @Mansi

Comment: @Awais it might be a function name typo, check all the steps now

Comment: yup i have tried it but the alert quickly comes and hide without pressing OK button. @Mansi

Comment: Hey got it , but one thing is still remaining, it finish the loginVC but at the back it shows the SigningAlert class xib still. @Mansi

Answer (score 0):

you can only dismiss the screen from main thread. If you trying it from asynchronus or non-main threads then it won't work.

Replace

```
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

With

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)                
 }
```

Comment: i have done that but still it isn't dismissing that. @Code cracker

Comment: can you please put the complete code of api call in answer please?

Comment: check it i have updated my question and pasted the API code. @Code cracker

Comment: you are not doing it on main thread please check my updated answer

Comment: i have tried in main thread before but it does not work. @Code cracker

Comment: you should do one thing, write dismiss outside of the success block and check whether its working or not out side of success block. so we can find the problem is with the way dismissing it or it's because success block

Comment: let me try. @ Code cracker

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, your question is

```
HomeClass -> present SigningAlert class -> present LoginVC class
```

So problem happen when you did not dismiss first Xib before you present second xib.

Solution: 
 In `IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {`, you can call delegate or something like this to notify to HomeClass known. In HomeClass you should function look like below

```
dismiss(animated: true) {
            let loginAlert = LoginVC()
            loginAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
             present(loginAlert,animated: true,completion: nil)
        }
```

UPDATE:
In your alertVC
@IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

```
let loginAlert = LoginVC()
loginAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

 // Note: post notification
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "shouldShowLoginVC"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)

// present(loginAlert,animated: true,completion: nil)
// self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
```

}

In your HomeClass, you should implement obsever to listen notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotif(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "shouldShowLoginVC"), object: nil)
```

And add handling function
    @objc func handleNotif(_ sender: Any) {

```
    // Dismiss first xib
    dismiss(animated: true) {

        // after finish dismiss first, present second
        let loginAlert = LoginVC()
        loginAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        present(loginAlert,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes the scenario is same as u describe, in which class i have to write this dismiss code? @baohung02

Comment: @Awais: what's result?

Comment: i got that in the above solution. Thanks for ur time and answer :) . @baohung02